# JUnit NoSuchMethodError for Assert.assertEquals

Tags: eclipse, junit

JUnit version 4.11
Eclipse Kepler

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(JJ)`

Yet no compile errors are generated and the build on the build server reports no errors.  I feel I have Eclipse misconfigured somehow.

Any Eclipse gurus out there that can figure this out, much appreciated!

Comment: Simple fix, sharing in case this happens to someone else out there.

I had an older JUnit in the project classpath.  The IDE was using a newer JUnit.  JUnit in the project was updated to 4.11 and it is all working now.

Answer (score 5):

I had an older JUnit in the project classpath. The IDE was using a newer JUnit. JUnit in the project was updated to 4.11 and it is all working now.